# Combining React and Flask Routing

Tags: flask

I'd like to handle all routing on the client side with two exceptions:

The server should handle any route that begins with /api and serve the files from /dist.

Here's my folder structure:

```
./
├── Client
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── bundle.js
│   │   └── bundle.css
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── __tests__
│   │   ├── components
│   │   └── index.tsx
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── tslint.json
│   ├── webpack.config.js
│   └── yarn.lock
├── README.md
├── app.py
└── requirements.txt
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="Client")

@app.route('/api/random')
def random_name():
    response = {
        'randomName': choice(["Ben", "Joe", "Robert", "Amy"])
    }
    return jsonify(response)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index(path):
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How can I serve `bundle.js` from `index.html`?
I've tried using `url_for` in the `index.html` but it doesn't work - I get a 404.